# XSLT date conversion - data format change

Tags: xslt

What's the options to show/output date in HTML in some sort of readable format. I mean if I simply show value of date_last_activity it looks wierd :S
So my question IS does XSLT offers any date format conversions at all?

XML:

```
<date_last_activity format="MMDDCCYY">04132012</date_last_activity>
```

XLS template:

```
<xsl:value-of select="date_last_activity"/>
```

HTML:

```
04132012
```

Would rather like it to look like 04/13/2012...

I readed a lot on XSLT one, I guess it's possible to make "template" => formatDate... but no idea where to start :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="date_last_activity">
  <xsl:value-of select=
  "concat(
     substring(.,
               string-length(substring-before(@format, 'MM'))+1,
               2
               ),
     '/',
     substring(.,
               string-length(substring-before(@format, 'DD'))+1,
               2
               ),
     '/',
     substring(.,
               string-length(substring-before(@format, 'CCYY'))+1,
               4
               )

         )"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied to the provided XML document:**

```
<date_last_activity format="MMDDCCYY">04132012</date_last_activity>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
04/13/2012
```

**When the same transformation is applied to the following XML document:**

```
<date_last_activity format="CCYYDDMM">20121304</date_last_activity>
```

the same correct result is produced:

```
04/13/2012
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do it n more than one place, create a named template somewhere in your xsl

**EDIT**: template didn't appear because of wrong formatting...

```
<xsl:template name="formats_date">
  <xsl:param name="raw_date" />
  <xsl:value-of select="concat( substring( $raw_date, 0, 2 ), '/', substring( $raw_date, 2, 2 ), '/', substring( $raw_date, 4 ) )" />
</xsl:template>
```

Then apply it as

```
<xsl:call-template name="formats_date">
    <xsl:with-param name="raw_date" select="date_last_activity" />
</xsl:call-template/>
```

Otherwise you can just do the xsl:value-of concat... stuff directly where you need it

Comment: Thanks for tip. But my issue is I don't know how to create named template, I've tryed tough :S

Comment: try again - I didn't format the code propertly and it disn't show

Answer (score 1):

XSLT 2.0 offers the function format-date(). However, before using it you will need to convert your date to ISO format, YYYY-MM-DD, which can be done using concat and substring.

If you're still stuck with XSLT 1.0, there's a library of date-handling functions and templates available at www.exslt.org.

Comment: Hello Sir,
Do you know where one can find an example of converting a date to ISO using concat and substring?
Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need an example? They are very simple functions. If you have a problem understanding the specifications, ask a new question. If you do understand the specifications but can't write the code, then I can't help you.

Comment: Well, the template required to convert my date format to ISO, in its entirety, ended up to be something quite more involved, but I was able to do it. I posted my code as an answer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605088/xslt-convert-date-format-to-iso/18991073#18991073