# XSLT convert date format to ISO

Tags: xslt

From *(Twitter format example)*

```
Tue, 15 May 2012 15:40:34 +0000
```

to *(ISO format example)*

```
2005-12-01T13:45:00
```

using XSLT

---

Here's an XML snippet

```
<item>
     <title>It's called "Kangaroo Care" - what parents can do to create a special bond and improve the health of their newborns: http://t.co/8MV8FpM4</title>
        <link>http://twitter.com/ProvHealth/statuses/202423233104973826</link>
        <description>It's called "Kangaroo Care" - what parents can do to create a special bond and improve the health of their newborns: &lt;a href="http://t.co/8MV8FpM4"&gt;http://t.co/8MV8FpM4&lt;/a&gt;</description>
     <pubDate>Tue, 15 May 2012 15:40:34 +0000</pubDate>
        <guid>http://twitter.com/ProvHealth/statuses/202423233104973826</guid>
        <author>ProvHealth@twitter.com (Providence Oregon)</author>
     <media:content type="image/jpg" height="48" width="48" url="http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/748948431/cross_normal.png"/>
     <google:image_link>http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/748948431/cross_normal.png</google:image_link>
        <twitter:metadata>
         <twitter:result_type>recent</twitter:result_type>
     </twitter:metadata>
 </item>
```

Comment: You need to say whether you need an XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some ideas about how to approach this.

1. you can do **substring wrangling** like in this example:
   [Format a date in XML via XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500915/format-a-date-in-xml-via-xslt).
   You will likely  have to create yourself a few "enumerables" for
   days of the week and months.
2. XPath 2.0 gives you [**XSD types constructor functions**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#constructor-functions-for-xsd-types) and
   you can get some help from these on top of substring wrangling.
3. if your transformer supports **EXSLT** you can go with the
   [date/time extension functions](http://www.exslt.org/date/index.html).
4. EXSLT also has [**regular expression** support](http://www.exslt.org/regexp/index.html) which you can
   use to parse the twitter date into chunks for further conversion
   into the ISO date.
5. you can write [a **custom extension function**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Extension-Functions) in whatever
   technology you use to drive your XSLT to run the conversion for you.

With that said, there's no one-function "easy" way to accomplish what you need in XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

This converts d/m/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM to ISO date. No time on this yet, but it would be a continuation of this. The fact that the day and month could be one character or two complicated it.

```
  <!--Convert from 'd/m/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM' to YYYY-MM-DD-->
  <xsl:template name="ISODate">
    <xsl:param name="Date" />
    <xsl:param name="Year" />
    <xsl:param name="Month" />
    <xsl:param name="Day" />

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not($Month)">
        <xsl:call-template name="ISODate">
          <xsl:with-param name="Month" select="substring(concat('0',substring-before($Date,'/')), string-length(concat('0',substring-before($Date,'/'))) - 1, 2)" />
          <xsl:with-param name="Date" select="substring-after($Date,'/')" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="not($Day)">
        <xsl:call-template name="ISODate">
          <xsl:with-param name="Month" select="$Month" />
          <xsl:with-param name="Day" select="substring(concat('0',substring-before($Date,'/')), string-length(concat('0',substring-before($Date,'/'))) - 1, 2)" />
          <xsl:with-param name="Date" select="substring-after($Date,'/')" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="not($Year)">
        <xsl:call-template name="ISODate">
          <xsl:with-param name="Month" select="$Month" />
          <xsl:with-param name="Day" select="$Day" />
          <xsl:with-param name="Year" select="substring-before($Date,' ')" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($Year,'-',$Month,'-',$Day)"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```